# I have a problem passing props from a state to the child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

This is the `Login` component where I created the authentication state with the `token` as false, and after login convert as true

```
function Login() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: '', email: '' });
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({ token: false })
  console.log(auth)
  const Login = (details) => {
    console.log(details);
    if (
      details.name === adminUser.name &&
      details.email === adminUser.email &&
      details.password === adminUser.password
    ) {
      console.log('Logged in');
      setAuth({
        token: true,
      })
```

This works perfectly fine, but now when I try to pass it to the `PrivateRoute` component, the `auth` is undefined

```
const PrivateRoutes = ({ auth }) => {
  console.log(auth)
  return (
    auth ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/login"/>
  )
}
```

Also this is my App.jsx

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
        <Route path="/*" element={<MainPage />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

What do I need to change to get the data from the state and my guard functionality to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `auth` state should be in a common ancestor so it can be passed down as props.

Example:

```
function App() {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({ token: false });

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<PrivateRoutes auth={auth} />}>
        <Route path="/*" element={<MainPage />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login setAuth={setAuth} />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

```
const PrivateRoutes = ({ auth }) => {
  return auth.token ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
}
```

```
function Login({ setAuth }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: '', email: '' });
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const login = (details) => {
    if (
      details.name === adminUser.name &&
      details.email === adminUser.email &&
      details.password === adminUser.password
    ) {
      setAuth({ token: true });
      navigate(/* new target path */, { replace: true });

    ...
  }

  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

So, to summarise, you want the state in the Login component to be able to access in PrivateRoutes component.
React recommends a pattern  called **lifting state up** to achieve such similar use cases .

The idea is to have the ***auth*** state variable **in common parent to both LoginPage component and PrivateRoute Component** and pass it to both child components.

Something similar to the below image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyPPu.png)

So now changing **auth** (state) in any one of the components will effect the other component too. You should pass down setAuth()  to the  component where you want to modify the auth state.

In your example, Login component must be able to modify **auth** so that PrivateRoute component can use that state. You need to **pass setAuth() to Login component** and **auth**  variable to PrivateRoute

Refer the docs [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components)

The answer by Drew Reese makes it clear with the code example. Please refer it.